# Understanding "hardlinks" (linux-like) on NTFS

Tags: ntfs, hardlink

I'm a bit off with the explanation for hardlinks, symlinks and junctions on NTFS. I want to have

```
c:\A\B\C
c:\C\B\A
```

be the *same* directory, just accessible thru to different pathes. So if I put a file in one, it should appear in both but still be one file on disk. If someone renames the B folder in the first path, both pathes should still point to the same directory. If one path gets deleted, the other should still be valid. If a file gets deleted, it should get deleted in all pathes, of course. So I basically want two names for the same directory.

Is this possible and if, what *is* the correct way to do this?

Comment: This is called hardlink. And btw you can try the three types and find differences before asking.

Comment: ... unfortunately hard link cannot be created for directories.

Comment: @i486 I did, thats why I asked, because all four didnt work as expected.